# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" error in my case

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

so i've tried to create constructor function that will access DOM elements with class "key" and create object with array of css properties that I want to assign to class through constructor (I don't know if that makes sense I am still learning OOP so it might be all wrong). Here is my code:

```
const key = document.getElementsByClassName("key");

function Com(k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8) {
    this.key[0].style.translate = k1;
    this.key[1].style.translate = k2;
    this.key[2].style.translate = k3;
    this.key[3].style.translate = k4;
    this.key[4].style.translate = k5;
    this.key[5].style.translate = k6;
    this.key[6].style.translate = k7;
    this.key[7].style.translate = k8;
}

const coms = {
    com1: ['translate(290px, 290px)', 'translate(290px, 290px)', 'translate(290px, 290px)','translate(0, 0)', 'translate(0, -290px)', 'translate(-290px, 0)', 'translate(-290px, -290px)', 'translate(290px, 290px)'],
}

const temp = new Com(coms[0]);
```

The error undefined (reading 0) is showing on this.key[0]... line.

I've checked if creating new object is wrong but it doesn't show any error in this line. Also i've changed const key to array with random numbers and the same error occcures. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: `coms` is an object (`{}` syntax) with one property named `com1`. Therefore, to access that array you need `coms.com1[0]` - using `coms[0]` will result in `undefined`. Also, your function takes 8 parameters but you only supply 1 - k2 to k8 will also be undefined. I'm assuming there is a bit more code you have not shown us? The rest of the class declaration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass an array and loop its objects

```
const keys = document.getElementsByClassName("key");

function Com(translations) {
    for (let i = 0; i < translations.length; i++) {
        keys[i].style.transform = translations[i];
    }
}

const coms = {
    com1: ['translate(290px, 290px)', 'translate(290px, 290px)', 'translate(290px, 290px)', 'translate(0, 0)', 'translate(0, -290px)', 'translate(-290px, 0)', 'translate(-290px, -290px)', 'translate(290px, 290px)'],
};

const temp = new Com(coms.com1);
```

get only one key

```
const key = document.getElementsByClassName("key");

function Com1(translation) {
        key.style.transform = translation;
}

const coms = {
    com1: ['translate(290px, 290px)', 'translate(290px, 290px)', 'translate(290px, 290px)', 'translate(0, 0)', 'translate(0, -290px)', 'translate(-290px, 0)', 'translate(-290px, -290px)', 'translate(290px, 290px)'],
};

const temp = new Com(coms.com1[0]);
```

Comment: Ok this fixed my problem but is it possible to create a new constructor object by targeting index from coms object, and not their name?

Comment: updated my answer for both